# How to have an mvc4 application start with a pre-existing user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, forms-authentication

I have developed an application in MVC4 using the entity framework and the default forms authentication. I have disabled account registration through the controller, and I want to instead have my application start out with a single user I define in the code somewhere. Then that user logs in and manages the creation of their user-base. Ok so maybe the design is slightly silly, but it's my boss's idea.

How do I seed UserProfile with an account to begin with? The only guides I can find assume you're using SimpleMembership, but I'm just using forms authentication.

Comment: if you already have the login code setup and working you just have to override it.  When it gets to the method to check the login, set the credentials

Comment: Ah, ok, I was thinking it would need its own seed function like with data creation for new models.

Comment: Why are you treating the first user differently from the rest?  There is no reason why the first user is authenticated and stored differently from the rest.